# can i use GA4 event to track a button that download a pdf?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

i'm trying to track the download of three pdf in a site. I setupped a event for each button, directly in GA4 using the event page. I also create a conversion for each event, but still nothing appear. I binded it to referer link and set the "referer" to the link that starts download

[the event list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCczo.png)

[the custom event that appear when i press "new event"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F44nJ.png)

EDIT:
it's working. I simply used GTM with the "custom GA4 event", setting on link click equal to referer (where referer is the link at pdf download)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: there isn't code right now. i simply added the js snippet in my page. btw now i update the question because i resolved using GTM